# Python problem with list - removing duplicates

Tags: python, list

I am quite new to python and trying to remove some duplicates from a list following below code. I am getting a list index out of range error which doesn't make sense to me. Thankful for any advice. 
Cheers
Kevin

```
names = ['Bob','Kenny','Amanda','Bob','Kenny']
num_items = len(names)
print(num_items)
print(range(num_items))
for i in range(num_items):
      counter = names.count(names[i])
      if counter >1:
            names.remove(names[i])
print (names)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-926264b9d757> in <module>
      4 print(range(num_items))
      5 for i in range(num_items):
----> 6       counter = names.count(names[i])
      7       if counter >1:
      8             names.remove(names[i])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It is not recommend to remove the element of list while use for loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: You can also convert your list to `set` and then back to `list`: `names = list(set(names))` (if order is not important)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. Let me know if this works

```
names = ['Bob','Kenny','Amanda','Bob','Kenny']
unique_names = list(set(names))

print(unique_names)
```

Comment: Python does not have a `unique` method on list

Comment: Oh shit, that's true. `unique_names = list(set(names))`, then.

Answer (score 5):

just use it like below:

```
names = ['Bob','Kenny','Amanda','Bob','Kenny']
names = list(set(names))
```

now names will be list with no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is simply a different data structure - a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). Whereas list like `[1,2,3,1]` is an **ordered** (we know which is first, which is second, etc) **sequence** of things, a **set** is **unordered**. We only know if something is, or is not in the set. Also, we can get all the elements in the set. And finally, the elements of the set must me **unique**.

Because of those properties you can simply make a set out of a list (**cast list to a set**) like **`set([1,2,3,1])`**, and you'll get only the unique elements. You can then print it like a list. It's performant and pythonic

Answer (score 0):

index out of range occurs because you are using for loop thinking there are n items.

But you remove an item during loop making the number of items to n -1, so when the code is trying to access the nth item, it is not able to see the item in list and thus the error.

```
names = ['Bob','Kenny','Amanda','Bob','Kenny']
```

there are 5 items once you remove duplicate

```
names = ['Bob','Kenny','Amanda','Kenny']
```

now there are only 4 items with max index of 3.

but you are looping with len(names) which 5 (max index 4)

so names[4] will throw index out of range

that is why you should not remove items when you are iterating it.

so to remove the duplicates you would do something like this

```
names = ['Bob','Kenny','Amanda','Bob','Kenny']
unique_names = []
for name in names:
  if name not in unique_names:
    uniques_names.append(name)
```

or you could use sets as mentioned in other answers

Answer (score 0):

For this you would definitely use convert it to a set.  The major advantage of using a set, as opposed to a list, is that it has a highly optimized method for checking whether a specific element is contained in the set. This is based on a data structure known as a hash table. If you are looking to continue storing only unique values, it will be best to leave it as a set.

```py
names = ['Bob','Kenny','Amanda','Bob','Kenny']
unique = set(names)
#unique = {'Bob', 'Amanda', 'Kenny'}
unique.add('Bob')
#unique = {'Bob', 'Amanda', 'Kenny'}
#when you are ready to convert it back into a list
names=list(unique)
```